# grub multiboot wont start 2nd windows installation

Tags: grub2, multiboot

I'm new to Linux - please help
I havent found an answer in the forums yet

I have 2 HDDs

The BIOS reports the HDDs in the following order:

- Third IDE Master = 200Gb drive
- Fourth IDE Master = 1Tb drive

The last 2 entries of Grub show:
 - Drive - 200Gb - Microsoft Windows XP ........ on /dev/sda1
 - Windows NT/200/XP (Loader) (on /dev/sdb1)

Windows XP (sp3) is installed on the 1st partition of both drives
Ubuntu (latest) is installed on the 2nd partition on the 1Tb drive

- Ubuntu loads fine from the 2nd partition of the 1Tb drive from the grub menu
- Windows XP loads fine from the 1st partition on the 200Gb drive from the grub menu
- Windows XP FAILS to load from the 1st partition on the 1Tb drive from the grub menu
- NB: this partition still contains all the windows files

When I select "Windows NT/200/XP (Loader) (on /dev/sdb1)" from grub I get:

- a black screen for a few seconds then it goes back to the grub selection menu

The default ubuntu (install alongside) config did not work so I used the advanced   partition manager to get it installed - [ubuntu works fine]

I selected  "Windows NT/200/XP (Loader) (on /dev/sdb1)" as part of the install process:

- I was just trying things to get it installed.

How do I change the grub entry "Windows NT/200/XP (Loader) (on /dev/sdb1)" to point to   the correct location to boot Windows XP on the 1st partition of the 1TB drive?

Thank for any help

Comment: when you log into ubuntu Have you tried **sudo update-grub** and seen if that fixed your problem?

Comment: Yes I did.  It rebuilds to the original grub menu - with  the same results.  I'm concerned that I told it the wrong thing when I selected "Windows NT/200/XP (Loader) (on /dev/sdb1)" in the partition manager and it is just going back to that??

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!